# Instantiate a module directive asynchronously using AngularJS and HeadJS

Tags: javascript-framework, head, angularjs

I created a custom directive attribute that will turn an ordinary select box into a ChosenJS (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) select box. To make the code cleaner, I want to load the external chosen.js plugin file asynchronously with HeadJS. Here is my AngularJS directive:

```
myApp.module.directive('chosen-select', function() {
  head.js(myApp.pathTo.plugin.chosen);

  head.ready(function() {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.chosen();
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    }
  })
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems that because I am loading it asynchronously, Angular doesn't know it exists and the directive is not working. Is there a way to programmatically inject a dynamically loaded module directive so that Angular knows about it and can update the view accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, directive function isn't returning a config object for the directive that's why it is failing.

Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('chosenSelect', function() {
  var el;

  // load chosen file
  head.js(myApp.pathTo.plugin.chosen);
  head.ready(function() {
    jQuery(el).chosen();
  });

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      // set el via closure, so that head ready callback has access to it
      el = element;
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. I did some quick and dirty debugging with some console.log's and it's never making it inside the directive. I am calling it in my view with `<select chosen-select multiple>`

Comment: Didn't cache it before; directive name must be CamelCased. I just updated my answer. If it still is not working for you, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Ah! I saw that and thought for sure you had found the issue... but nope - still isn't working. [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/3dB3d/9).

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nishp1/3dB3d/11/. I had to wrap el in jQuery for animate to work as there is no animate method in angular also I had to set no-wrap(body) below the Choose Framework in Fiddler.